# .upper Command not Working

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently making a text based rpg, and to solve the problem of case sensitivity during inputs, I used .upper to make it all uppercase. However, it seems to not work in my code. Can someone please help?

```
 if weapon in normalswords or weapon in fireswords or weapon in airswords or weapon in grassSwords:
                if weapon in normalswords:
                    print (normalswords[weapon])
                    while y== True:
                        variable= input("Equip? Yes or No")
                        variable.upper()
                        if variable== "YES":  
                            print (weapon, "Equipped")
                            x= False
                            y=False
                        elif variable == "NO":
                            x= True
                        else:
                            print ("That is not a valid answer")
                            y=True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) *returns* a copy of the string converted to upper case. It does not modify the string inplace because strings are immutable in Python.

Try this:

```
variable = variable.upper()
```